# How to check if data written to stdout has been read by other process in Rust?

Tags: rust, stdout

I am writing a tool that continuously writes data to `stdout` in Rust, and program#2 will read data from my `stdout` at a **varied** frequency.

I have to write data at max frequency in order to avoid program#2 from hanging. Here is an example code of my current implementation:

```
use std::io::Write;
use std::{io, time, thread};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {

    let mut data = [0u8; 256];
    let mut counter = 0u32;
    // program#2 will read from its `stdin` every 20ms ~ 30ms
    let min_period = time::Duration::from_millis(20);

    loop {
        let start_time = time::Instant::now();

        // complex data processing
        data[..4].copy_from_slice(&(counter.to_le_bytes()));
        // write to stdout
        io::stdout().write_all(&data)?;

        let elapsed = start_time.elapsed();
        if elapsed < min_period {
            thread::sleep(min_period - elapsed);
        }
        counter += 1;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

But I don't want to keep too many data in `stdout` buffer because it will introduce latency if the data process logic has changed. That's why I want to check whether the previous data has been read by program#2 before writing new data to `stdout`, something like:

```
use std::io::Write;
use std::{io, time, thread};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {

    let mut data = [0u8; 256];
    let mut counter = 0u32;
    let one_ms = time::Duration::from_millis(1);

    loop {
        if (/* data in stdout has been read yet?*/) {
            // complex data processing
            data[..4].copy_from_slice(&(counter.to_le_bytes()));
            // write to stdout
            io::stdout().write_all(&data)?;
            counter += 1;
            
        } else {
            thread::sleep(one_ms);
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Is it possible in Rust? Or are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [`BufRead::fill_buf`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#tymethod.fill_buf)?

Comment: @JishanShaikh I'm afraid no, this method if for stdin only, but I need to check info of stdout.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a _pipe_ for communication between the two processes. A pipe is for one-way communication only. The operating system will manage a pipe buffer for you, and if the buffer fills up, further writes to the pipe will block. This is the only way of knowing that the process on the reading end of the pipe hasn't read the data yet. The size of the pipe buffer varies depending on the operating system. On Linux, it's been 64KB for many years now.

Comment: If you want bidirectional communication between the processes, you should probably use a socket instead of a pipe.

Comment: This isn't really a question about Rust. What platforms do you want the code to run on? Do you also control the code of the second program?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for the info, the application runs on Ubuntu, unfortunately, program#2 is developed by other team and I don't even have source code. Guess I can only use the first solution and write until the buffer is full.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it might be off-topic, but if I can set pipe buffer size to the size of data, it should have similar outcome, can we do it in Rust?

Comment: I don't think the pipe buffer size can be modified. There's a "pipe size" you can set using `ulimit`, but that seems to be something else (the largest buffer size for which writes are guaranteed to be atomic).

Comment: @SvenMarnach: From `man 7 pipe`: Since Linux 2.6.35, the default
       pipe capacity is 16 pages, but the capacity can be queried _and set_ using the fcntl(2) `F_GETPIPE_SZ` and `F_SETPIPE_SZ` operations.  See fcntl(2) for more information.

Comment: Also, in the same man page there is this function call `ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &nbytes);` to get the number of unread bytes in the pipe, using a handle for either end of the pipe, which may be useful for the OP.

Comment: @rodrigo Nice, looks like I was completely wrong. I didn't think this was possible, and I only did a quick search on SO, which appeared to confirm my assumption.

Comment: The duplicate can be used in Rust using either the `libc` or the `fionread` crates.